# Dynamically Adding Tab At Specific Position to TabView Primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

How do we dynamically (from java program) add a tab to existing TabView primefaces component.

My situation is something like this,
There is a drop down with some values, 
whenever user selects some value from drop down,
We need to add a tab dynamically at specific position to TabView.

I know we can get existing TabView component, and add a tab,
But if we want add a tab at particular position , how ?

```
public void addTab(){
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        TabView tabView = (TabView) fc.getApplication().createComponent(
                "org.primefaces.component.TabView");
         Tab tab1 = new Tab();
         tab1.setTitle("Dynamic Tab-1");
         tabView.getChildren().add(index,tab1);
}
```

Comment: Try this ....    tabView.getChildren().add(index, tab1)

Comment: Ohh Yeah, thank you so much it works.
But if i want to add any content i.e. an xhtml page,
to that tab as contents, how can i add ?

Answer (score 0):

You should update the view to reflect the new tab. Use RequestContext for ajax update.

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
context.update("tabview");
```